# Microsoft Query in Excel - Using a cell value to define a source

Tags: vba, excel, microsoft-query

I am new to Microsoft Query, so my terminology may not be standard.

I am setting up an Excel Document to act a s a dashboard. The Document will sit on a shared folder across multiple users.

I have created a sheet in Excel, in which I have a cell that reads the path of the Excel Document.

I plan to use a Microsoft Query to use the path located in lets say `"Sheet1(A1)"` to find all the files in this directory and combine them.

On running the query, I can set it up so that it does this.
I however come into issues when trying to combine the files in this directory. It works on my local machine, however when a user tries on another machine, using their credentials, the Path used to find the input is hard-coded to my path.

How can I carry the `"Sheet1(A1)"` value into the query / transformation, to allow the path to remain dynamic?

Below is a brief outline of my workflow:

The "Source" for the first part of the import reads. Where "path" refers to a named cell located in Sheet1(A1):

```
= Folder.Files(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="path"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

I thin out the source by filtering only for a specific term in the filename (there are multiple).

```
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "AS") or Text.StartsWith([Name], "As"))
```

This is where the hard coding begins, I then take the filtered the files and expand and combine the sheets into one.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Transform File from Query1 (2)", each #"Transform File from Query1 (2)"([Content]))
```

This is where the path is hard coded, and I want to use the value in cell A1.

```
= #"Filtered Rows"{[#"Folder Path"="**C:\Users\User\Path\**",Name="As_Test.xlsx"]}[Content]
```

As I said the Source of the query works, but I cannot carry that Dynamic text through, or at least am not versed in the query syntax to carry it through.

Comment: Would you be able to concatenate in the value? I was just looking at the following by GeraldArtman https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95dd4361-cffb-4b12-820a-85c3d041db3e/power-query-query-with-parameter-from-a-cell?forum=powerquery Don't know if any use.

Comment: Thank you. I have come across this during my searches. I wasnt able to implement the solution, due to my limited understanding of how the syntax.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use Microsoft Query for this?

Comment: @Zac Primarily because it seems to be an easier method of taking my sampling data and process it for a the users I have. I plan to have the folder constantly updated (almost hourly with new data). I am however open to suggestions.

Comment: This help https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Get-and-Transform-Data/Power-Query-Combine-Data-from-Folder-with-Relative-Paths/td-p/119568   and its sub link https://www.howtoexcel.org/power-query/how-to-import-all-files-in-a-folder-with-power-query/   The last one looks quite good

Comment: So let me get the gist of what you are attempting to do: you want to look in the folder (specified in `Sheet1("A1")`) and create a new excel file by combining all the excel files in that folder? If so, what do you mean by **`combining`** them? do you mean that you just want all the sheets in the files and copy them into the new file?

Comment: @QHarr Thank you I will look this over now

Comment: @Zac - The gist of the process is Sheet1(A1) contains the formula to get the path of the Excel Document (A Master Document). The Document sits in a folder containing a number of sampling datasets, which are constantly being added to. The purpose of the Master is to filter through the incoming samples and only present that information to the user which is necessary or more readable. By combine I mean merge all the sampling datasets into a single table in the Master File.

Comment: Your code samples are M code, so you are NOT using Microsoft Query, the old tech that has been around for yonks, but you are using Power Query/Get&Transform

Comment: @teylyn Thank you for clarifying that! I assumed it was M Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With current versions of Excel, Power Query (called Get and Transform in Excel 2016) will do a much better job than Microsoft Query, but judging from your code samples, you are not using Microsoft Query at all, but you are indeed using Power Query.

You can use a cell in the worksheet that stores the current folder path from the perspective of the user who opens the file. You can then feed that path as a parameter to the Power Query.

The formula

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
```

will give you the path to the current file. (if it doesn't make sure the workbook is saved, not a new file)

There are a few different ways how you can use the cell value as a parameter in Power Query. One option is to have this formula in a parameter table, as described by Ken Puls in his article about [parameter tables for Power Query](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/), just your scenario.

Comment: Thank you. That link explained it perfectly.